# Google Cloud Datastore: StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED with owner service account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-iam

Seemingly out of the blue, I'm unable to access my datastore from my Google App Engine project.
One moment everything works, the next I'm getting "StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED" errors.

I've properly installed the json key from a "owner" service account, set it up in my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

I've even set up a new project, with the same results.
Since yesterday, it just won't work.

I raked the whole internet. Where shall I look?
Most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found it: I was importing a third-party library that was setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to its own json file, overwriting access of the main project to the owner account.

Comment: Which library did that?